# Dependency on Session variable while calling Service Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, session-variables

There are two projects in solution.

Web (ASP.NET MVC 4 - Strictly the presentation layer) and

ServiceAccess (ClassLib - Strictly for calling REST API's and returns results to Web layer)

When a User Logins, we recieve token form REST Service and save it into current session. Session["UserToken"] = token;
All Rest Service calls needs to be authenticated, thus Controller from Web calls ServiceAccess using current "UserToken" in session.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{

      private IProductServiceAccess ServiceAcc { get { return new ProductServiceAccess( Session["UserToken"] as string); }

      public ActionResult Index()
      {
            IEnumerable<Products> products = ServiceAcc.GetAllProducts(); return View();
      }

}
```

Please consider that at the moment we don't care depedency of Controller on ServiceAccess(not using unit testing).

I'm concerned about, is it a bad approach to use current session variables while accessing methods from Class Liberary ? Isn't tight coupling of layers ServiceAccess and Web (based on session variable token) a bad approach ?
What would be the right way to call SeviceAccess methods using current Token in session ?

Comment: It would be bad if `ProductServiceAccess` accessed `Session` but it doesn't, it just takes a string, so you haven't really coupled your service layer to the Web layer.

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer ! Looks like I'll stick to my current implementation then.